# (#4) Application request limit reached - ADS API

Tags: ads, facebook-ads-api

Earlier today my application started receiving this API return:

```
{
    "error": {
       "message": "(# 4) Application request limit reached",
       "type": "OAuthException"
       "code": 4
    }
}
```

The call in question is this:

I've understood the problem, but I wonder if I can do something to increase the limit of calls.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Where is the call in question ?

Comment: And at what rate are you making the calls?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually being reported as a bug.  If they changed the rate limits it's news to all of us confused folks hanging out on the thread below ;)

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/442544732471951?browse=search_50ca0e8ed9fa97632231355